# How to replace objects in scene with a group instance?

Tags: linked-data, instances

[This is the new group I made.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Q35.jpg)Hello blender community,

Currently I have instanced a building's interior. However I need to Make a better version of each object. I have created a new group which has multiple meshes inside. I do not wish to manually place everything again.

What i wish do do is replace the simple walls in the scene with the new group "wall_LOD_00". So the simple wall acts as a scale, rotation and  position data, but gets replaced by the objects in the group. Ideally the group would be an instance.

I noticed there is an option "ctrl + L" for linking. I was able to change the object meshes data, but I am unsure how I replace an object with a group instance. 
[image: The basic object i want to b replaced.]
Any help would be great,
many thanks
memeseco

Comment: It's hard to understand without any screenshot, but have you tried linked duplicated objects (alt D) instead of instance groups, I find it more convenient than instance groups but maybe instance groups have advantages that I ignore.

Comment: I edited my post and added some basic pictures. I did not use my building in the screenshots. I just want the group "Cube with a hat"  to replace the object i clicked. I want it to Instance and replace the basic cube with the Group "cube with a hat"

And yes Mr moonbot, I have used Alt-D extensively :) Thanks

Comment: I don't know if you can easily replace an object with a group, or a group with a group. But let say you want to replace the cube A with the group B, you could join (ctrl J) the different objects of your group B to make a unique object, then in the Properties > Data, in the top dropdown menu, give its mesh the name you want. Now select the object A, and in properties > Data, in the top dropdown menu, select the mesh of the object B. You could also change the composition of your group A, removing (ctrl alt G) or adding (ctrl shift G) any object. Also, why don't you use linked duplications?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I come from a 3ds Max background so i am still trying to find the best solution. Thank you for the reply and confirmation of my findings. I noticed the Ctr + J. However that breaks what I need so i am unable to do that. 

I am currently looking into Linked duplicates more so, I have been using linked Duplicates "Alt+D", one thing that confuses me is why when I add an object to a linked duplicated the Duplicates don't get the additional model? Thank you again, Mr MoonBoots.

Comment: If you want to add an object to a linked duplication you must first select the additional object, then the duplicate, then ctrl J, now all the linked duplications will have this new object in their mesh. If you first select the linked duplication then the additional object, then ctrl J, the duplication is not linked any more to the others.